# Int-Enum to String and vice a versa in Swift

Tags: performance, swift, enum, extension-methods

I have a situation in my client-server app where I have to send my network strength to server and also receive other clients' strength from server.

So I created enum as:

```
enum NetworkType: Int {
    case none, gprs, two_g, three_g, four_g, lte, wifi
}
extension NetworkType: Comparable {
    public static func < (a: NetworkType, b: NetworkType) -> Bool {
        return a.rawValue < b.rawValue
    }
}
```

I can use this as:

```
if NetworkType.two_g < NetworkType.three_g { 
    print("low network") 
}
```

But for sending to server, I have to convert it to String and vice a versa.
So I added one more extension as:

```
extension NetworkType {

    static var networkDict: [String: NetworkType] = ["gprs": .gprs,
                                                     "2g": .two_g,
                                                     "3g": .three_g,
                                                     "4g": .four_g,
                                                     "lte": .lte,
                                                     "wifi": .wifi];
    init(rawString: String) {
        let loweredStr = rawString.lowercased()
        self = NetworkType.networkDict[loweredStr] ?? .none
    }

    func rawString() -> String? {
        return NetworkType.networkDict.allKeys(forValue: self).first
    }
}

//Dictionary extension for 'key for value'
extension Dictionary where Value: Equatable {
    func allKeys(forValue val: Value) -> [Key] {
        return self.filter { $1 == val }.map { $0.0 }
    }
}

let network = NetworkType(rawString: "gprs") //gprs, while receiving from server
let rawString = NetworkType.gprs.rawString() //"gprs", while sending to server
```

It is working fine, no issues.
Jus curious to know if theres any better way to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

Is the `.none` case really needed? It serves as a "fallback" in `init(rawString: String)`
if an unknown string is received from the network. But it is not listed in
the mapping dictionary, i.e. it can not be converted back to a string.

My suggestion is to remove that case, and use a failable initializer for the 
conversion from a string:

```
init?(rawString: String) {
    let loweredStr = rawString.lowercased()
    guard let type = NetworkType.networkDict[loweredStr] else {
        return nil
    }
    self = type
}
```

Using a custom extension for the conversion to a string is not really necessary,
the same can be achieved directly with

```
func rawString() -> String? {
    return NetworkType.networkDict.first(where: { $1 == self }).map { $0.0 }
}
```

But the real question is: Why does this return an optional? It would return `nil`
if one of the enum cases is not covered in the dictionary. Let us assume that
you add another case `five_g` in the enumeration and forget to update the dictionary.
Now `NetworkType.five_g.rawString()` returns `nil`. What string do you send to the
server?

One possible approach would be to force-unwrap the string, so that this
*programming error* is detected early:

```
func rawString() -> String {
    return NetworkType.networkDict.first(where: { $1 == self }).map { $0.0 }!
}
```

But there is still a chance that the error remains undetected during development
and the deployed application crashes later.

---

A safer (and actually shorter and easier) approach is to define a *string-based*
enumeration, which implicitly defines the conversion to strings
and back:

```
enum NetworkType: String {
    case gprs
    case two_g = "2g"
    case three_g = "3g"
    case four_g = "4g"
    case lte
    case wifi
}
```

To make the comparison work, an ordinal number is associated with 
each case:

```
extension NetworkType: Comparable {
    var ordinal: Int {
        switch self {
        case .gprs: return 1
        case .two_g: return 2
        case .three_g: return 3
        case .four_g: return 4
        case .lte: return 5
        case .wifi: return 6
        }
    }

    public static func < (a: NetworkType, b: NetworkType) -> Bool {
        return a.ordinal < b.ordinal
    }
}
```

Now the conversion is done using the built-in methods:

```
// String to NetworkType:
if let network = NetworkType(rawValue: "gprs") {
    // ..
} else {
    // unknown string from network
}

// NetworkType to String:
let rawString = NetworkType.gprs.rawValue
```

The conversion to a string cannot fail anymore. If another case is added, the *compiler* ensures that it is added to `var ordinal` as well.

Comment: if removed `none` how can handle no-connection? not for sending but for other uses like checking while trying to connect to server, etc

Comment: If you use an optional `NetworkType` can "no connection" can be represented as `nil`. – But that was just a suggestion, you can keep your `none` case if that fits your needs better.

Comment: @D4ttatraya Thanks for the edit suggestion. But I intentionally did not assign the raw string if it is equal to the case name, because that is the default.

Comment: Ohhkay then! Nice tip actually